# background image with multi screen

Tags: android, multiscreen

I have different folders with different background images for every screen size, also i have created folders for the layouts, the content in each folder is copy & paste (the layout ones) cause i want it to look the same but take the matching pictures for the density.

I don't know why but the application looks great on my phone and very bad on my tablet (background pictures are blurred)

Comment: It could be as simple as that your phone has good density and your tablet does not.  I know the Samsung Galaxy S4 has ~460 pixels per inch and my Motorola Xoom has around ~160 ppi so it won't look as good regardless from one device to the other as far as cripsness goes on the larger screen.

Comment: so i don't need to have different layouts?